# Run blocked application in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, security

I have an old Windows XP system running inside a VirtualBox because I have some very old programs which run only in Win XP.

Now I changed my printer and wanted to install the new printer (HP Envy 6000, [driver setup file](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/printers/EN6000/HPEasyStart-12.8.9-EN6000_51_2_4771_1_Full_Webpack.exe)) in this Win XP system.

However if I execute the setup file of the driver, Windows blocks the execution because of an unknown source (in my case in German "Unbekannter Herausgeber"). This is maybe because of a missing or old signature.

Since the system runs inside a VirtualBox without internet connection and without any security risks, I want to disable this blocking mechanism completely. At least I want to run the driver setup file.

So how can I do this?

**Edit**

I tried to disable driver signature checks in system settings as described [here](https://www.devicedriverfinder.com/blog/device-drivers/signed-drivers-and-unsigned-drivers) (My Computer -> Properties -> Hardware -> Driver Signing button -> Ignore) without success.

Comment: "Unbekannter Herausgeber" is _Unknown Issuer_. See [_Issuer Name_ in X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Structure_of_a_certificate).

Comment: [Which installation software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Installation_software) is this setup running with?

Comment: It's this driver: https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/printers/EN6000/HPEasyStart-12.8.9-EN6000_51_2_4771_1_Full_Webpack.exe

Comment: This [installer is from 22. Apr. 2021, Betriebssysteme: Windows 10 (64 Bit)](https://support.hp.com/de-de/drivers/selfservice/hp-envy-6000-all-in-one-printer-series/29256672). I'm not sure if it even works on XP even after resolving the certificate issue. The issuer of the certificate associated with the installer is: _Issuer: CN = Symantec Class 3 SHA256 Code Signing CA_, _Serial number: 037e56a19d56788e01f12630951bf5cc_. If there's no option to skip verification at setup (I still investigate.) you will have to get this issuer's certificate somehow into your Windows XP's certificate store.

Comment: This is not just a driver, this is _HP Easy Start Printer Setup Software + Driver_. With just a driver of 192.4 MiB you could print millions of newspaper pages a day on [a 100+ m long printing line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_printing#/media/File:DE-Zeitungsrollenoffsetdruck_by_Steschke.jpg). :)

Comment: There was also a smaller file: https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/COL107186/mp-275092-2/HPEasyStart_13_4_8.exe I will try this as well. But didn't find any other driver for this printer. So if you have another file I could try, let my know

Comment: Giving the XP VM temporary Internet access is not an option?

Comment: What could I do with temporary internet access?

Comment: The installer/Windows could download the issuers certificate.

Comment: The smaller file I linked in the comment above gives another error: "Der Prozedureinsprungpunkt "LCIDtoLocaleName" wurde in der DLL "KERNEL32.dll" nicht gefunden"

Comment: Ok, I will try it with internet access... but same error with internet access.

Comment: This smaller one is even newer _HPEasyStart_13_4_8.exe_ than the bigger one _HPEasyStart-12.8.9-...exe_. I told you I'm not sure about modern SW on XP.

Comment: Shouln't it be sufficient to have an appropriate inf file in win xp?

Comment: Do you have one?

Comment: If I extract the exe file, there are some inf files (e.g. HPRestStub.INF or HPWinUSBStub.inf or hpygid32.inf)

Comment: Go, give it a try.

Comment: Doesn't it says that the file doesn't contain information about the hardware.

Comment: Then I guess you're out of luck unless you find a driver/installer that was made for XP. But if this isn't a printer that's equally old I'm pretty sure that there isn't such.

Comment: The software you downloaded doesn’t support Windows XP and there absolutely is no way to run it on Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

There are a few workaorunds I can think of if there is no XP installer/driver available for your printer:

- Print to a file ([PS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript), [EPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript), [XPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification), PDF, ...) and actually print it on your host system.
- Setup a printer on your host system as network printer and access it from the XP guest system.

Comment: Indeed I use the first mentioned workaround for now. Regarding the second one: Can you give some more details about this? The host is a linux (ubuntu) system.

Comment: @Julia There's [CUPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS) but I think this is a topic for another question...if there isn't already one covering this. It'd be astonishing if there wouldn't be one here or at SO or at askubuntu.